# Syncing iPad with iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, data-synchronization, music

I have an iPhone and recently purchased an iPad, and I'd like to sync all the song's I've already got in my iPhone, into my iPad. How can I do this?

I have iTunes but cant seem to sync.

Comment: You may have to list a little more details. I'd start with editing your question to say you followed this article - http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1386 - and just explain what doesn't make sense. There will be one step where you "don't get it" and that will help us help you.

Comment: Could you provide the error message that you are getting as well?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have all of your iPhone songs already loaded in your iTunes library. If you previously synced iTunes on your computer with your iPhone, this is most certainly the case.
2. Connect your iPad to your computer and run iTunes
3. In your iPad from within iTunes, navigate to the "Music" tab and make sure that the "Sync music" and "Entire library" options are ticked.
4. Click on the Apply button.

Your iTunes library songs will now be pushed to your iPad.

You can alternatively enable iTunes match on both your iPhone and your iPad, and have iTunes Match push your iPhone songs to your iPad. More information about iTunes Match here:

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4914